# localhost page not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

when I create an admin folder and then add an empty razor page and do /admin, it tells me the page cannot be found. However I have another User folder and when I do /User it works.
These folders are listed in a Views folder.
I tried duplicating the User folder and renaming it to Admin but it didn't work.

```
 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Admin";
        });

            //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionSqlite")));
            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders(); 
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, MailJetEmailSender>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a `Controller` (`AdminController`) with an Action that returns view.

Comment: Do I need to add/change anything?                                                                       
  public class AdminController
    {
        public IActionResult View()
        {
            return View();  
        }

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by Dimitris Maragkos. After you add the View under the Admin folder. You need to create `AdminController` under the Controllers folder. You could add MVC Empty Controller and rename it. Keep the content as it is in the controller and run the project. Visit `/Admin`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a view named `Index.cshtml` in the path `Views\Admin\Index.cshtml` then you should create a `Controller` named `AdminController`:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); 
    }
}
```

Notice the method name (`Index`) is the same as the view name.

If you want to have different method name and view name then you need to specify the view name when you return the view:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult View()
    {
        return View("Index"); 
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio